# scrollTop value is not getting changed

Tags: scroll, scrolltop, onkeydown, onkeyup

I am trying to change the value of scrollTop for the element on keydown, but each time it is returning 0. 
These are the methods used to do the operations:

```
autocompleteUp: function (autocompleteList) {
  if (this.current > 1) {
    this.current--
    this.select(this.node[this.current])
  }
}

select: function (el) {
  let index = [].indexOf.call(this.node, el)
  if (index === -1) return

  this.current = index
  console.log(this.id.scrollTop)

  let elHeight = el.scrollHeight
  let scrollTop = this.id.scrollTop
  let viewport = scrollTop + this.id.scrollHeight
  let elOffset = elHeight * this.current
  console.log('select', this.current, ' height', elHeight, ' viewport', viewport, ' elOffset', elOffset, ' scrollTop', scrollTop)

  if (elOffset < scrollTop || (elOffset + elHeight) > viewport) {
    // console.log(document.body.scrollTop)
    // document.documentElement.scrollTop = elOffset
    console.log(this.id.scrollTop)
    this.id.scrollTop = elOffset
    console.log(this.id.scrollTop)
  }
}
```

[This is how console look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjgOd.png)

Comment: can you show a fully reproducible example? if you can share a jsfiddle.net link much better.

Comment: I can share the screenshot as there are dependencies with this.

Comment: Perhaps the element isn't scrollable? I notice `document.body` and `document.documentElemenet` in your example, which of those is scrollable will depend on browser and quirks. Use document.scrollingElement for the top level scroller.